# How do I differentiate between files with the same name in Meld?

Tags: meld

I'm comparing two files with the same name. How do I know which one is which in the two panels? Using win10.

[image]

Comment: From their site https://meldmerge.org/images/meld-filediff-full.png suggests that the path of the files should be show in the area just above the diff. Is this not the case? What do you see? A screenshot might help.

Comment: Hmm. This [bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/-/issues/84) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889856/copy-path-from-meld-window) question suggests that the field type used to show the detail has changed to something less useful. The bug report suggests it is now "fixed" somehow while the AU question has a couple of options. What version are you running?

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: looking at the meld github the issue was fixed sometime after October last year while 3.20.4 was released before that in August. You should probably update your version to something newer. The notes from 3.21.1 seem to suggest there is something in it https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/-/releases/3.21.1 "A new custom per-pane location display widget replaces the standard GTK+
file chooser button and our existing placeholder path display,"

Comment: But 3.20.4 is the latest Windows version: https://meldmerge.org/

Answer (score 1):

On the left is the file that you specified as the first argument when calling `meld`, on the right is the file specified as the second argument.

Comment: I had a feeling that it's not random. However, I never ran it from the command line. I have a couple of tools that use it, and I prefer not to start memorizing which one calls in which order, or how I executed them. I don't think it's such an outstanding request to be able to view the full file name?